Add horizontal lines y-axis ggplot
I have a dataframe like data:
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Generate database
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2023-01-01"), to = as.Date("2023-12-31"), by = "day"),
  value = runif(365, min = 50, max = 100)
)

# Create ggplot
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())


I would like to include horizontal light gray lines for each of the values represented in the y-axis automatically. I have tried the following code without any success:
# Create ggplot
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  geom_hline(yintercept = value)


Any help?

What does "values represented" mean? Are you looking for panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "gray")?

Thanks for the answer. values represented mean that i want a line for each y-axis value (in this case> 50, 60, 70, 80, 100). Best

To render a horizontal line for each of the breaks in the y scale, use
theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray"),
  )


Try to add this piece of code before printing the ggplot:
unique_values <- sort(unique(data$value))
for(i in 1:length(unique_values)){
  p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = unique_values[i], color = "lightgray", linetype = "dotted")
}

you can adjust the color and the linetype as you want

I think p + geom_hline(yintercept = unique_values) should suffice.

Thanks for the answer. However, I do not want to have a single line for each y value, but for each y-axis value (in this case> 50, 60, 70, 80, 100). Best
